# Regex to get substring including beginning and end values

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I want to use regex to pull out a string including the beginning and end values.

For example:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("A Bylaw(.*?)" + @"\.");
var v = regex.Match("blah blah blah A Bylaw to provide for the government and management of the Water Works System in the City and the collection of Rents, Rates, and charges for water. blah blah blah");
```

This returns:

> to provide for the government and management of the Water Works System
>   in the City and the collection of Rents, Rates, and charges for water

I'm looking for:

> A Bylaw to provide for the government and management of the Water
>   Works System in the City and the collection of Rents, Rates, and
>   charges for water.

Comment: Do you want to achieve what you describe, or to achieve it with regexes ? Cause you can probably achieve the same results with usual string methods...

Comment: If your question has been answered please mark as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

just change your regex to include them

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"A (Bylaw.+?\.)");
```

http://rubular.com/r/4GRUECzqfx

Answer (score 0):

Regex regex = new Regex("(?i)A Bylaw(.*)\.");

This gives you the match result not bothering about the case of "A Bylaw".

If the text which you pass has "A BYLAW", then this works perfectly..

@Sam I am , appreciate for the link which you posted.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you try to extract the phrases that contains a keyword from a text, to do that, you can use : `var regex = new Regex(@"(\.|^)?([^.]*Bylaw.*?(\.|$))");`
https://regex101.com/r/KjxWWC/1

- `(\.|^)?` will match a dot or the beginning of the text, useful for the first phrase
- `[^.]*` will match anything that is not a dot
- `Bylaw` is what you are searching
- `.*?` will match anything until...
- `(\.|$)` will match the closing dot of the phrase

Note that if you use it on a text `var matches = regex.Matches("...")` the result will be in `matches[n].Groups[1]`.